# Differences between LED and LCD monitors, from a consumer's perspective

Tags: display, lcd, led

I'm researching possibly getting some LED monitors to replace my LCD ones.

What are the practical differences between LED and LCD monitors that a consumer would notice?

I'm looking for things like brightness/clarity differences, noise generation (ie: does a LCD monitor generate more noise than a LED monitor), etc. What would a scrupulous consumer notice as major and minor differences between the two display technologies?

Comment: Are you referring to *LED-backlit screens*? I.e. does a link to [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LED-backlit_LCD_display) answer your question?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm referring to.

Comment: I think your question refers more to the 2 types of backlighting of LCD monitors, as most of the monitors now are LCD. . The "florescent" or CCT (cold cathode) or LED (light emitting diode) . . Interesting other things to check out are the panel type, like IPS and the pluses and minuses of those . . Watch out for the color, either one can generate noise , and can depend more on the quality of the build.  NITS , lumens ,  candellas per sq mm, etc are the specs for Brightness, and they are very loosly defined :-) in specs (often meaningless specs). IMO you should See what your getting.

Comment: There does exist "LED monitors" that are not LCD panels being backlit. The OLED displays, are leds themselves providing the actual color and light. OLED is not a backlight, through a panel of light valves (LCD). OLED displays are a completely different world of display. OLED and LED displays without a LCD panel are way less common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having recently switched from Traditional LCD to LED-Backlit, I would say that I have noticed the following:

1. The brightness can be higher on LED screens, but by default the power settings are often switched to reduce energy consumption and so out of the box the LED may look dimmer than a comparable LCD screen.
2. The LED lamps that light the screen are very noticeable when viewing a largely black image, as opposed to LCD where the blacks are varying depth depending on the quality, but uniform in their depth.
3. LED monitors consume noticeably less power, as in, my old LCD monitor would dip the lights in my apartment when it turned on, and the LED does not.
4. Clarity are noise are comparable, and anyway has more to do with resolution and the power of the image processor. For the same price, you can purchase higher response rates (measured in Hz) in LCD monitors than LEDs.

Comment: Wow.  If an LCD monitor dipped the lights in your place, I can only imagine what would have happened if you had a CRT!